# Probability Vehicles Parked

Tags: probability

A used car lot parks its vehicles in two rows, each consisting of 5 vehicles.  There are two trucks and eight cars for sale, and the vehicles are parked randomly. Determine the probability that the two trucks will be at either end of the same row.

Edit: This is what I have so far _ _ _ _ _ row 1 _ _ _ _ _ row 2 the trucks can park at the ends of either rows. There are 10 spots to park. 2 ways to park @ the ends of either row. # of possible ways to park is 2. 10*2/10 = 20/10 = 2:1

Comment: Hi, Grade 12 Math Help! This is an interesting problem that you are probably expected to do your own work on.  Can you please edit the question to include what you have done so far and where you are stuck?

Comment: I just edited my question

Answer (score 1):

Suppose one truck is black and the other is silver.

In how many possible ways could the two trucks be parked in the lot?

Since there are ten spaces in the lot, the black truck could be parked in ten ways, leaving nine ways to park the silver truck.  Thus, there are $10 \cdot 9 = 90$ ways the two trucks could be parked in the lot.

How many of these outcomes are favorable?

There are four spots at the ends of the two rows in which the black truck could be parked.  Once the black truck is parked, there is only one way to park the silver truck at the opposite end of the same row.  Hence, the number of favorable outcomes is $4 \cdot 1 = 4$.

Thus, the probability that the two trucks will be parked at either end of the same row when the vehicles are parked randomly in the lot is 
$$\frac{4}{90} = \frac{2}{45}$$

Comment: Isn't this different than considering the 2 trucks of same color? The question doesn't imply that there is 2 different colors for the trucks, and if they are both of same color then the total possible number of ways that the trucks could be parked is $_1$$_0$$C_2=45$ and not 90. But also the number of favorable outcomes will be $2$ since the order is not important for us. But are these 2 methods correct? Or is it by chance that the answers are the same?

Comment: @FareedAF  Both methods are correct.  You divided the number of favorable ways the parking spaces could be selected by the number of ways the parking spaces could be selected.  I divided the number of favorable ways the trucks could be parked by the number of ways the trucks could be parked.  I used two different color trucks as a way of distinguishing between the trucks.  Since I used ordered selections and you used unordered selections in in both the numerator and denominator, we arrived at the same answer since both by numerator and denominator are twice yours.

Comment: @FareedAF  I suggest you post your method as an answer.

Comment: If the trucks are always at opposite ends of a row, I agree  that the chances are $2/45$ of being in the same row. Your reasoning was good; I missed that in my answer..  But, consider the condition if both trucks are parked at the same end of a row. If we swap truck positions, that would be another 4 chances of being 'at the end of the row'. That would make the chances $4/45$.

Comment: @poetasis No, it would not.  There are two ways for the trucks to be parked at the ends of a row.  Since there are two rows, that gives a total of $4$ favorable cases.  For the sample space, there are $10$ ways to park the first truck and $9$ ways to park the second truck, giving $90$ possible outcomes.  Hence, the probability is $\frac{4}{90} = \frac{2}{45}$.  If you instead consider parking spaces, there are $\binom{10}{2} = 45$ possible pairs of parking spaces the trucks could occupy, of which two are favorable (the ends of each row), again giving a probability of $\frac{2}{45}$.

Comment: What I'm suggesting, in the case of both trucks parked on the same end, is that for each 'end' there are two ways the trucks could park. They could swap positions on that end.

Comment: @poetasis  The favorable cases are those in which the two trucks are at opposite ends of the same row.   Either the black truck is on the left and the silver one is on the right or vice versa.  There are only two possibilities for each row.  Since there are two rows, there are a total of four favorable cases.

Comment: I agree with your reasoning about parking at opposite ends of the same row. My argument is about parking both at the same end of a row. The same logic works except that, on any given end, the trucks could swap positions making 2 chances of how they could park at that end.

Comment: @poetasis  That is true, but the question is asking for the probability that the trucks park at opposite ends of the same row.  It sounds like you interpreted it to mean that both trucks are at the same end of the same row.

Comment: Agreed, I went back and read more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

The total possible number of ways that the trucks could be parked is $\binom{10}{2} = 45$, and the number of favorable outcomes will be $2$ since the order is not important; by this I mean that if truck $T_1$ was at end 1 and truck $T_2$ at end 2 (of row 1) it is the same as $T_1$ being at end 2 and $T_2$ being at end 1(of row 1)
This is will be the same case, so this implies that the probability that the two trucks will be parked at either end of the same row when the vehicles are parked randomly in the lot is 
$$\frac{2}{45}$$